# What monadic type return return function

Tags: haskell

This function is strange. I'm confused.

```
return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
```

If i wrote return 5, I will get monad with 5 inside. But what type? Typeclasses are only named dependencies, not types. Monad is List, IO ... but this is undefined monad type.

Comment: Type inference, type inference and type inference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` is polymorphic so it can stand for more than one type. Just like `+`  in C is overloaded to work both at summing ints and at summing floats, `return` is overloaded to work with any monad.

Of course, when its time to run the code you need to know what type the `m` corresponds to in order to know what concrete implementation of `return` to use. Some times you have explicit type annotations or type inference that lets you know what implementation of return to use

```
(return 5) :: [Int]
```

Other times, you can "push up" the decision higher up. If you write a larger polymorphic function, the inner returns use the same type from the outer function.

```
my_func :: Monad m => a -> m a
my_func x = return x

(my_func 10) :: [Int]
```

I told my func that I was working on the list monad and in turn, this made my_func use the list monad implementation of `return` inside.

Finally, if you don't leave enough information for the compiler to figure out what type to use, you will get an ambiguou intance compilation error. This is specially common with the `Read` typeclass. (try typing `x <- readLn` in ghci to see what happens...)

Answer (score 2):

It's polymorphic. It returns whatever monad instance's `return` implementation was called. What specific data type it returns depends on the function.

```
[1,2,3] >>= \n -> return $ n + 1 -- Gives [2,3,4]
getLine >>= \str -> return $ reverse str -- Gets input and reverses it
```

Comment: Thanks, and second small question, Haskell has build in list, but I can't find list of typeclasses which build in list use. Thanks to http://learnyouahaskell.com/ I now, that lists has Functor, Applicative and Monad typeclasses, but this is not a full list of typeclasses.

Comment: @Seraph: The built in List type is just a straight datatype and list functions are monomorphic and only work on that datatype. For a more generic "iterable" concept that are things like Traversable and Foldable.