# What is the type of return 5 in Haskell when no context is given?

Tags: haskell, monads

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071729/what-monadic-type-return-return-function) the OP asks what the type of the expression `return 5` is and the answer has already been given in that question: it is a generic type, as can be verified by typing

```
:t return 5
```

in the Haskell interpreter:

```
return 5 :: (Num a, Monad m) => m a
```

The specific implementation of `return` is determined by the context in which it appears: type inference will restrict `m` to a specific monad such as `Maybe`, `[]`, `IO`, and so on.

I can also force the interpreter to pick a specific monad by specifying the type, e.g.

```
Prelude> return 5 :: Maybe Int
Just 5
Prelude> return 5 :: [Int]
[5]
```

and so on.

Now if I type the expression `return 5` without specifying a type, I get:

```
Prelude> return 5
5
```

which is quite surprising to me: I would rather have expected the interpreter to tell me that it cannot pick an appropriate implementation of `return` because it cannot infer the monadic type to be used.

So my question is: what specific monad has Haskell used here? And based on what criteria was this monad chosen?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer! In fact, if I try to compile this program:

```
module Main
where

a = return 5

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "This program should not compile"
```

I get an error:

```
No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a use of `return'
The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  a :: m0 Integer (bound at invalid_return.hs:4:1)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
  instance Monad IO -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
  instance Monad [] -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
  ...plus one other
In the expression: return 5
In an equation for `a': a = return 5
```

So it only works in GHCi for the reasons explained by Jon.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't infer `a :: (Num b, Monad m) => m b`

Comment: If you want to compile the program, enable `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The monad is `IO`. This is a minor quirk of the behaviour of GHCi. It tries to unify the type of your input with `IO a`; if it succeeds, it runs that `IO` action and tries to `show` the result. If you give it something other than an `IO` action, it simply tries to `show` the value.

It’s for the same reason that these produce the same output:

```
Prelude> "hello"
"hello"
Prelude> print "hello"
"hello"
```

Comment: Ok, so the result is of type `IO Int`. This makes sense.

Comment: @Giorgio No, `IO Integer`. The number is defaulted according to Haskell's normal defaulting rules.

Comment: @kosmikus: See my extra example: 5 has indeed gotten type `Integer`.