# Inconsistent do notation in functions

Tags: haskell, monads, type-mismatch, do-notation

Why is this function allowed:

```hs
-- function 1
myfunc :: String
myfunc = do
  x <- (return True)
  show x
```

and this is not:

```hs
-- function 2
myfunc :: String
myfunc = do
  x <- getLine
  show x
```

The compile error:

```
Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
Expected type: IO Char
Actual type: String
```

I get why function 2 shouldn't work, but why then thus function 1 work?

and why does this then work:

```
-- function 3
myfunc = do
  x <- getLine
  return (show x)
```

I get that it returns `IO String` then, but why is function 1 also not forced to do this?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I added the compilation error @RobertHarvey

Comment: Because `show x` is a `String`, which is the same as `[Char]`, so the types all match up when the `do` block is in the List Monad. Whereas that option isn't available in the second one, since the use of `getLine` forces the Monad to be `IO`.

Comment: Not in this case. `x <- (return True)` wouldn't compile since then you essentially are saying this: `(return True) >>= (\x -> _)` thus a lamba without a body which is not allowed.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I still don't really understand. What I thought was happening is that the return True is of type IO String or IO [char] if you will. Is that not the case then?

Comment: `return True` has type `(Monad m) => m Bool`. GHC will, if possible, infer which Monad `m` makes sense in context. When the return type is `String` then only `m ~ []` can ever work.

Comment: PS your title is strange as the question has nothing to do with referential transparency.

Comment: @RobinZigmond the title is this way primarily because I think that function 1 is not referentially transparent. It of course is, but I don't see how. Since I can get a String type out of a function that uses a do-block

Comment: @RobinZigmond if it is Monad m where m ~ []. Shouldn't the return type of function 1 be different then?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info and the answer linked from there.

Comment: also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728131/849891), search for "axiomatically".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In **function1** the `do` block in `myfunc` is working in the list monad, because `String` is really just `[Char]`. In there, `return True` just creates `[True]`. When you do `x <- return True` that "extracts" `True` out of `[True]` and binds it to `x`. The next line `show x` converts `True` into a String `"True"`. which being the return value the compiler value expects to see, ends up working fine.

Meanwhile in **function2**, the `do` block in myfunc is also working on the list monad (for the same reason, `String` being really `[Char]`) but calls on `getLine` which is only available in the `IO` monad. So unsurprisingly, this fails.

-- EDIT 1

OP has added a **function3**

```
-- function 3
myfunc :: String
myfunc = do
  x <- getLine
  return (show x)
```

No this should not work for the same reason **function2** fails.

-- EDIT 2

OP has updated  **function3** to fix a copy paste error.

```
-- function 3
myfunc = do
  x <- getLine
  return (show x)
```

This is mentioned in the comments, but for clarity sake, this works because, when the type information is unspecified, GHC makes it best inference and after seeing `getLine`, it figures it’s `IO String` which does provide `getLine`.

Note - I wrote this answer with as casual a tone as I could manage without being wrong with the intention of making it approachable to a beginner level.

Comment: Then why would it work if I changed it to `return (show x)` ?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer Unless I'm missing something, that shouldn't work from what you have given us- as `getLine` should not be available otherwise. Do recheck your code structure again.

Comment: I should have left out the type indeed, it is a copy paste error. The type in that case becomes an IO String.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer Ah I see. Yes if you leave out the type, GHC infers the type for you. It saw `getLine` and inferred that you were working on `IO String`.

Comment: I think I figured it out now. I was thinking function 1 would not be referentially transparent. But this is of course only applicable to IO types. I was thinking `x <- (return True)` would be of that type. But apparently it somehow is not, still not sure why tho

Comment: It doesn't "extract" `True` so much. What it really does is basically produce `[[True]]` and flatten that to get `[True]`.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer This might not be related to referential transparency. Perhaps you're confusion is more about how `return True` works in a function that has nothing to do with `IO`? If so that is because, `String` being a synonym for `[Char]` is really just a list; so now you're working inside a list monad. Within this list monads's do block, a `return True` just creates a list with True in it.

Comment: But return is of type Monad a => b -> a b. So why is then function 1 not of type a String?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer because `b` is `Bool`.  `a` is `[]` in this case (because of the last line of the do block is a `String` = `[Char]` = `[] Char`, forcing the monad to be `[]`).  So `return True` has type `[Bool]`.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer In the first line of function1, `return True` is definitely not String. However remember, we are still within the List monad here (`String` really being `[Char]`). So the `b -> ab` part in `return`'s type would look like something like this in the List monad - `b -> [b]`. So here, `return` does `True -> [True]`. So you could pretty much rewrite that line as `x <- [True]` which eventually results in `x` bound to `True`. Obviously `True` is not a String, but your next line did `show True` which creates the string "True". Hope that explanation cleared it up for ya!

Comment: So the compiler is essentially looking from the end of the function? It sees that show x is used so it infers that Monad [] should be the previous type?

Comment: Since you explicitly set function1's return type as `String`, the compiler doesn't need to infer at all and will expect to see a `String` as the return value at the end of the do block here.

Comment: I see, but I can omit the type signature and it still gets the right type. How does that process work in this case? Since the type True has nothing to do with List. I assume it looks at the last part first?

Comment: Yes, if you omit the type signature, GHC will infer one based on the function definition. It is generally advised to not assume that GHC will end up inferring what you want, so when possible be explicit with the type signature. About your 2nd question, yes "the last part" being the the return value is one way of looking at it.

Comment: Yeh some compiler trickery then. This post explained it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932794/what-is-the-type-of-return-5-in-haskell-when-no-context-is-given

Comment: type inference is not "guessing" though.

Comment: @WillNess you are correct. I was doing my best to not mention words like inference etc. that might distract a potentially confused beginner.

Comment: we could say "derive" or "determine".

Answer (score 9):

`do` blocks work in the context of an arbitrary `Monad`. The `Monad`, in this case, is `[]`. The `Monad` instance for lists is based on list comprehensions:

```
instance Monad [] where
  return x = [x]
  xs >>= f = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
```

You can desugar the `do` notation thus:

```
myfunc :: String
myfunc = do
  x <- (return True)
  show x

-- ==>

myfunc = [y | x <- return True, y <- show x]

-- ==>

myfunc = [y | x <- [True], y <- show x]
```

In a list comprehension, `x <- [True]` is really just the same as `let x = True`, because you're only drawing *one* element from the list. So

```
myfunc = [y | y <- show True]
```

Of course, "the list of all `y` such that `y` is in `show True`" is just `show True`.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing confusing about this is the use of Monad []. Since I say return True I would assume it would be Monad Bool(don't know if it exists) instead of Monad []. Does the compiler do some trickery or is there is simple explanation for that too?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer, no trickery. Just look more carefully at the type of `return`. `Monad` is what's sometimes called a "constructor class", because its argument is a type constructor rather than a base type.

Comment: Yeh I think it is clear now. Return did Monad m => a -> m a so then the Monad type [] is used which is then returned. I was completly confused, but turns out [] is just a Monad and string is just [char] so it all works out! Thanks a lot